# Publish .net core console App as FDD not an option?

Tags: .net, publishing

I have multiple small helper console apps written in C# using .net core. When I try to publish them through Visual Studio I only have the option "Portable" in target runtime. I cannot deselect it. This makes so the output includes runtimes which I do not need.

If I try to use the CLI to publish running only the "dotnet publish -c Release" command it still includes the runtimes.

I have tried to update the .net core SDK and app to 2.2, which did not give me more options and Google is no help either.

Following is a csproj of one of the console apps:
[.csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Ni9.png)

Following is my publish options in VS 2017:
[publish options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj2P6.png)

I have searched google for countless hours trying to find a solution. But every solution I have tried still includes the runtimes when publishing.

So this is my last resort and really hope that someone here has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to publish them through Visual Studio I only have the option "Portable" in target runtime. I cannot deselect it.

`Portable` is (as far as I am aware) the Framework-dependent deployment (FDD) option in Visual Studio 2017.

> If I try to use the CLI to publish running only the "dotnet publish -c Release" command it still includes the runtimes.

This [official Microsoft documentation on publishing .NET Core apps with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) clearly identifies `dotnet publish -c Release` as the FDD option for the command line.

> [T]he output includes runtimes which I do not need.

A bare-bones "Hello World" console application (`dotnet new console`) created in .NET Core 2.2 and published with `dotnet publish -c Release` produces four files in its *publish* folder (e.g. `appname.deps.json`, `appname.dll`, `appname.pdb` and `appname.runtimeconfig.json`).

In contrast, a fully Self-contained deployment (SCD) of the same default "Hello World" console application published with `dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained true` (RIDs listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)) has approximately 217+ files (212-non program .dlls) and is ~66mb.

I am uncertain if you mean these 212 .dlls when you say you have unnecessary runtimes. But if these aren't what you mean, then as a suggestion, you may wish to look into your own code (or the `Enums` and `SharedHelpers` projects, for example) for more insight into this issue.

Another option might be to simply de-duplicate any runtimes produced (e.g. use the same runtimes for multiple applications, as applicable).

Comment: Hello Anaksunaman. The problem is really that when I use the standard command "dotnet publish -c Release" it still publishes the app as an SCD, with the runtimes which I don't want. I simply cannot get it to just publish as an FDD.

The enums / sharehelpers projects are just class libraries so the problem should not be there.

Comment: You could use the option `--self-contained false` to turn off the SCD.